# Rails where query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, query-optimization

i have to write query

```
circular_ids = [array of ids about 500 elements]

flyers = Flyer.where(flyer_id: circular_ids)
```

but my database have died during request

How to optimize it?

Comment: Possibly use https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches to find in batches? `Flyer.where(flyer_id: circular_ids).in_batches(of: n)`

Comment: Are you sure your table's indexed properly? How many records in this table?

Comment: @tadman about 200k records

Comment: If your database "dies" as in crashes then you have a database problem you need to resolve first. That's not a lot of records. Is `flyer_id` indexed or not?

Comment: no indices on `flyer_id`

Comment: so it should be easy for database to do `where` statement with 500+ ids ?

Comment: did you make sure ids are actually an array of IDs and don't contain anything weird, or nils?  Also may be good to call `.uniq` on the array in case there may be duplicates, although that shouldn't break anything.

Comment: @lacostenycoder array already prepared, only uniq elements no nil's

Comment: couple of debugging suggestions... try these in the rails console 1. change the query to `Flyer.where(flyer_id: circular_ids).count` and see how many results are returned. Since this doesn't instantiate many Flyer instances it should be quick. 2. try the (original) query with a small subset of circular_ids, and then a larger subset, etc and see if the result is getting dramatically slower with larger and larger circular_id set.

Comment: What does the SQL look like?